# Access doorkeeper_token (or current_user) in Active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, doorkeeper

I'm working on Rails API made with [RocketPants](https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants). For JSON serializing I use [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), and for OAuth - [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper).

The problem is with accessing `current_user` helper method in  `class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`. Error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `request' for #<UserSerializer:0xb5892118>)
```

`current_user` helper uses this snippet:

```
User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
```

and `doorkeeper_token` is:

```
def doorkeeper_token
    methods = Doorkeeper.configuration.access_token_methods
    @token ||= OAuth::Token.authenticate request, *methods
end
```

So as I find out, there is no `request` object accessible in `Serializer`. How can I make it accessible? Or should there be other way to implement `current_user`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's an open issue for this: https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants/issues/102

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the correct answer is to use `scope` object, included in `active-model-serializers`. But there were some problems: 
If I just try to access `scope` in `Serializer` - it's `nil`. I've tried to define it directly through `serialization_scope :current_user` and got `no method error`, as such method wasn't included... 
Then I've included needed module:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < RocketPants::Base
    include ActionController::Serialization
    ............
```

And got strange behaviour: it now was complaining about `can't use 'merge' on Nil`. Digging into gem's code I've found function

```
def default_serializer_options
  {
    :url_options => url_options,
    :root        => false
  }
end
```

, which was overriden in `ActionController::Serialization` and was empty function there, so that was the point where I got `nil`.

I've had to change that function to return `super` - now it wasn't complaining about errors, but then there was still `nil` instead of `scope`. This I managed to repair by including `:scope => serialization_scope` in `default_serializer_options`. Now I'm able to access `scope` object as intended.

Still don't know, why it is such a long path with strange patching required, while I can't google any of such cases.

Please, if someone can clear this for me, do it =)

Comment: The only reason this isn't working as expected is because RocketPants isn't passing the `scope` object through. How did you go about overriding `ActionController::Serialization` safely in your Rails project? I'd like to use your workaround.

Comment: @RobSobers oh my god, that's a crazy question after such a long time. I've gone c++ long ago, but I can try to find source of the project where I had this problem and just give it to you.

Comment: Thanks @morodeer! I struggled with this for a few hours and still couldn't get the `scope` variable to be non-nil. I have a really awkward workaround right now that doesn't use a serializer, so no worries if you can't find it. Would be nice to get a patch.

Comment: @RobSobers, looks like I haven't committed last changes in that project before stopping working with it. Maybe the similar post in my [blog] (http://morodeercoding.blogspot.ru/2013/12/rocketpants-activemodelserializers-wtf.html) can help more than this one. That's the maximum I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

I've honestly never really used this stuff, but from looking at the code and documentation, it appears that `ActiveModel::Serializer` makes the `current_user` available from the controller but it does so via the `scope` attribute of the serializer. So within the serializer, if you need to check whether the `current_user` is an admin, for example, you'd do that like:

```
if scope.is_admin?
  #your code here
end
```

Comment: Somehow `scope` is nil in my case. Still can't find how to use it with Doorkeeper and RocketPants